# Apache - Redirecting https to a different domain without security alert

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I've been investigating and searching information about it, but couldn't find any answer. The situation is the following:

I have an apache web server configured for the domain my_domain.com. It is configured using ssl, and has a wildcard ssl certificate installed on it, and it's working right.

Now, I'm trying to redirect requests to several domains like my_domain.net, my_domain.co.uk, etc to my_domain.com. I'we already set up the DNS records to point to my_domain.com.

I've set up the virtual hosts, and they're working correctly; the following would be the configuration for one of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName my_domain.co.uk
Redirect 301 / https://my_domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I open a browser and point to my_domain.co.uk, I get a security alert in the browser, regarding an invalid certificate on the server. Of course, http requests are working correctly (through different virtualhosts definitions).

Is there any option to fix this, apart from getting a new certificate that includes all the domains I want to redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid the security alert. SSL handshake happens before any http communication, so you either generate certificates for those domains, or you will have to live with that "warning".